# Server error, WCF service disabled

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, authentication, iis

I am implementing a basic authentication WCF service in ASP.NET using Visual Studio 2010. I accomplished this by roughly following the first few parts of [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515342.aspx).

I have the default ASP.NET Web Site (in VS2010) login page set up to use my WCF service to authenticate a user, using this code-behind and an `<asp: Login>` property:

```
protected void Login_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    bool isAuthenticated = false;

    string customCredential = "Not used by the default membership provider.";
    bool isPersistent = LoginUser.RememberMeSet; // Authentication ticket remains valid across sessions?

    AuthenticationServiceClient authClient = new AuthenticationServiceClient();

    isAuthenticated = authClient.Login(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.Password, customCredential, isPersistent);

    e.Authenticated = isAuthenticated;
    authClient.Close();
}
```

Furthermore, I had this working when I used IIS Express, but I have since moved to IIS 7.5.

When the above function gets called, an exception is thrown on the call to `authClient.Login(...)`.

The usual error page pops up with this to say:

> Server Error in '/AuthClientSite' Application.
>
> AuthenticationService is disabled.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: AuthenticationService is disabled.

As this code is nearly identical to what worked on IIS Express, and given that it seems like my service is just disabled, I'm guessing its a setting somewhere in IIS that needs to be fixed.

I am wrapping the `System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService` service as seen in [the link from above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515342.aspx).

Any ideas of what's going on would be a great help. I've tried so many different things over the past few days I can't remember and/or list them all, but I'll do my best to answer all your questions/comments.

Comment: what is the Identity under which App pool of IIS7.5 running? Is the app pool in running or stopped?

Comment: I'm new to all the lingo, but my sites are running with Identity: "ApplicationPoolIdentity" according to IIS Manager. Its status is "Started" so I'm guessing its running. Also, its v4.0 .NET and Integrated Pipeline Mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out my problem. I needed to add these lines to the Web.config file in the web site running the service:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <authenticationService enabled="true"
                requireSSL = "false"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs into this problem in the future.